# Inject passwords in IE's autocomplete list

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

Can I inject my own passwords into IE's autocomplete list?
I have a webapp in which I have multiple usernames and passwords. And as time goes, IE learns all these passwords. But alas, the time of reinstall comes, and IE is yet again a password virgin... Now... Is there any way to inject this username/password list into IE's storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an external password manager to take care of your passwords in a more secure and efficient way.

Since you like IE, you might want to take a look at LastPass which is compatible with just about all main-stream browsers.

The free application stores your passwords securely on the cloud and are accessible from any computer with internet access. This means that even if you reinstall, all you need to do is download the application again and login to have access to all of your autocomplete information. (LastPass also takes care of other types of forms if you want it to.)

Check it out at: http://www.lastpass.com

By the way, I just remembered, I'm pretty sure LastPass can also import your old IE passwords so you don't have to do that by hand.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.backsettings.com/internet-explorer-backup.html) is a freeware utility which allows you to backup and restore IE settings, including saved passwords.